# How to correct bind property to textbox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, binding, textbox, inotifypropertychanged

I write these code in mainpage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox x:Name="xxx" Text="{Binding Test}" TextChanged="xxx_TextChanged" />
            <Button x:Name="click" Click="click_Click" Content="click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

And these in mainpage.xaml.cs

```
  private string test;
    public string Test
    {
        get { return test; }
        set 
        {
            if (test != value)
            {
                test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Test");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public  void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void xxx_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Test);
        Debug.WriteLine(test);
    }
```

But Test isn't binded to textbox, when I write smth to textbox Test isn't changed.
What I doing wrong and how to correct that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `BindingMode` to TwoWay:

```
Text="{Binding Test, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

The other thing I've noticed, is that your binding to work need `DataContext` to be set, but you don't do that in your example. One way to do this would be something like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ContentPanel.DataContext = this;
}
```

If staying in Xaml is preferred, you can use `RelativeSource` property to bind to your page in Xaml, without setting DataContext:

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                               AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, //or Page
       Path=Test, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Another thing, `Test` will be set not after every character you type in your TextBox, but after user will finish editing text, for example by switching active control to next one.

Comment: Where I must set DataContext?  And Test isn't set. I create button, and on button click writeline Test, after I write smth on textbox and click button, Test is null

Comment: Thanks, now it works after setting Datacontext. Can I do it by another way setting Source and Path ?

Comment: When you write Text="{Binding Test}" you need framework to tell where to find Test, you can do it, by setting DataContext property on this elements or their ancestors, for example you can do it on your Grid. Sample code added to post.

Comment: Ok, but can I do same, by setting Path=Test and Source smth tell that it is the same page ?

Comment: In general, setting DataContext like this is a way  to go, if you want to stay in Xaml, you can do something like that:
`Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Test, Mode=TwoWay}"` (Change Window to Page in your case) This will set your source relatively for first Page that is an ancestor of your control, remove setting DataContext then